# Why are the timestamps on my removable media taken as UTC time?

Tags: debian, time, removable-storage

I'm running `Debian 8`, and all of the files on my removable media (SD cards, USB sticks) show up with the time stamp interpreted as `UTC`, rather than my local time?  What's going on?  `date` gives me the correct local time (in PDT).  This wrong time issue is only happening with removable media.  Never saw such a problem on my previous GNU/Linuxes!

```
$ uname -v
#1 SMP Debian 3.16.7-ckt25-1 (2016-03-06)
```

**Examples** (with non-date output deleted):

On my work-mac this morning:

```
$ touch /media/newfile; date; stat /media/newfile
Mon May  2 08:34:47 PDT 2016
"May  2 00:00:00 2016" "May  2 08:34:46 2016" "May  2 08:34:46 2016" "May  2 08:34:46 2016"
```

On my Debian 8 system at home:

```
/media/disk$ touch newfile2; date; stat newfile2
Mon May  2 21:53:42 PDT 2016
Access: 2016-05-02 21:53:42.000000000 -0700
Modify: 2016-05-02 21:53:42.000000000 -0700
Change: 2016-05-02 21:53:42.000000000 -0700
```

ls output showing change in time on "newfile" (should be 08:34)

```
/media/disk$ ls -al newfile*
-rw-r--r-- May  2 01:34 newfile
-rw-r--r-- May  2 21:53 newfile2
```

Comment: Can you show an example?  `touch /media/newfile; date ; stat /media/newfile`

Comment: @BowlOfRed     I made newfile on different computer (mac) and newfile2 on my Debian system.  Both times were locally correct, but the file made on the mac was interpreted as UTC when I went over to Debian.

Comment: @BowlOfRed     I'll put my output in the original question, since I can't format it right in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is either always use UTC as your timezone for all devices accessing the media or don't use FAT32 but NTFS or similar for your removable media :

The way Windows and Linux store timestamps differ, and there are intractable problems due to the fact a file timestamp is stored in local time but the timezone is not stored.

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/windows/desktop/ms724290(v=vs.85).aspx and http://www.pascal-hacker.de/info/it/sw/dst.htm for details.

Comment: NTFS isn't going to work for me -- none of my cameras will recognize a card formatted that way.

Comment: Then configure your cameras to use UTC and use the `tz=UTC` mount option on the Linux side, and the equivalent, if available, on OS X.

Comment: I'm using `mount from util-linux 2.25.2` and it appears that the `tz-UTC` option is always on, which was causing me grief.  I'll either go to UTC on my cameras or figure out how to always automount the sd cards with the `time_offset=-480` option (which I'll have to change twice a year).